# Java-Storing values in a while loop

Tags: java, drjava

I am a beginner in Java and I have an assignment on loops. I know this question may sound very basic to you but I couldn't find an understandable answer. My code basically looks like;

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Histogram
{
  public static void main( String[] args)
  {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in);

    // Constant

    final String CH = "*";

    // Variables
    int number;
    int count;
    int start;
    int width;
    int line;
    String output;


    // Program Code

    count = 0;
    number = 0;
    start = 1;
    width = 0;
    line = 0;
    output = "";


    // Creating the loop

    while ( start == 1) 
    {
      System.out.println( "Enter the numbers");
      number = scan.nextInt();

      if ( number < 0 )
      {
        start = 0;
      }

      else
      {  
        while ( width < number)
        {
         output = CH + " " ;
         width = width + 1  ;  
         System.out.print(output);
        }
        width = 0;


      }
    }

  }
}
```

This runs perfectly but the output of stars are printed after each user input. I want to store the output from each loop and print them together at the end when an negative integer is entered. How can I store the outputs that I don't know how many of them will be entered by the user?
In short I want to have the following output

Enter the numbers : 3 5 6 4 -1  //numbers are user inputs

3 ***
5 *****
6 ******
4 ****

Comment: if you wanted to, you could create a String variable to hold all lines. And you could just append output + "\n" so that your end string would look like

output1
output2
output3 etc.

Comment: simply if you things are going together then use them separately (not in else)and use either array or list to store your data

Comment: Do you want to print the output for each iteration in a different line ?

Comment: In your case you could use a `List<String>` to store the lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Histogram
{
  public static void main( String[] args)
  {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in);

    // Constant

    final String CH = "*";



   int count = 0;
    int number = 0;
    int start = 1;
    int width = 0;
    int line = 0;
    String output = "";
    String store="";


    // Creating the loop

    while ( start == 1) 
    {
      System.out.println( "Enter the numbers");
      number = scan.nextInt();

      if ( number < 0 )
      {
        start = 0;
      }

      else
      {  
        while ( width < number)
        {
         output = CH + " " ;
         width = width + 1  ;  
        store+=output;
        }
        width = 0;


      }
    }
    System.out.print(store);

  }
}
```

Comment: The output is the consecutive stars but I want to have each on a different line so I changed store+=output to store+=output+"\n" but then each stars become under another what can I do?

Comment: So okay ı found the answer thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

You just have to create a variable (something like `String` or `StringBuilder` *(preferred)*) outside the scope of while and instead of directly printing your result, you'd append whatever's the output, to this variable and print it at the end.

Using this approach, you're basically collecting the entire output and printing it all at once.

```
...

//create a output variable outside while loop. You can also use simple String
StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();

while ( start == 1) 
{
  System.out.println( "Enter the numbers");
  number = scan.nextInt();

  if ( number < 0 )
  {
    start = 0;
  }

  else
  {  
    while ( width < number)
    {
     output = CH + " " ;
     width = width + 1  ;  

     //instead of directly printing, you can append your output to out variable.
     out.append(output);

    }
    width = 0;


  }
}

//after coming out of the loop, you can now print it
System.out.print(out);

...
```

Answer (score 0):

In the "else" you could just store the numbers entered:

```
List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>(); //previously defined
(...)
else {
      myList.add(number);
}
```

and then outside the while loop, once populated your arraylist:

```
for(int i=0;i<myList.size();i++)
{
     for(int j=0;j<myList.get(i);j++)
     {
         System.out.print("*");
     }
     System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a List, for an example an ArrayList, instead of an Array as the size can grow dynamically.

For example,

```
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>();
ints.add(5);
ints.add(2);
ints.add(7);

for(Integer i : ints){
  System.out.println(i);
}
```

If you don't want duplicates, you could use a Set instead.